# What is the meaning of "set on you" in George Harrison song?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "[set on you](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xry_ooH9yY0)" in George Harrison song?

I've read the whole song thinking it will help me to understand based on the context but I'm still not sure about the meaning. Second, I've checked [the dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/set) for the meaning of the word set and it doesn't make sense to me. Then I found an idiom "[set on](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/set-on-upon-sb)" which means to attack someone... Does this meaning makes sense for the song?

Comment: The full expression is: ***to have one's mind set on something***.

Comment: "set on" can mean "focused on".  "set on" can also mean "desiring to, intent on {having or doing something}"

Answer (score 3):

As you can tell by the dictionary definitions you looked up, "set" is a versatile and contextual word and it's hard to list it's synonyms conclusively.

When an entity is "set on" something, it's been assigned, affixed, or otherwise focused on that thing. One's "mind being set" can mean that their decision is made, and in this case even suggests preoccupation or obsession with the subject. The line and song are about devotion to a chosen person.